# Using "The" before a specfic name

Tags: definite-article

I have this sentence:

> I changed [the?] command `doc('t.xq')` in front of [the?] variables `$p` and `$q` with [the?] variable `$db` as follows. Now it works (plus, I used [the?] function `last()` to have the last (lowest) common ancestor).

Is my usage of "The" in brackets, before specific names correct?

Is it a mandatory rule? Could they be said with or without "the"? What would be the difference?

Comment: I think if I read it either with or without the sentence would be absolutely fine. In the first case  `doc('t.xq')`  should be after "command" though.

Comment: @writingthesis you say I always can say them with or without "the"?

Answer (score 3):

I agree you can use "the", or leave it out. You don't have to be consistent and always use "the", or never use it. As a native British English speaker I would probably write

> I changed the command `doc('t.xq')` in front of variables `$p`
>   and `$q` with the variable `$db` as follows. Now it works (plus, I used
>   function `last()` to have the last (lowest) common ancestor).

but I can't explain **why** that "sounds right" to me, sorry!

Often in this type of writing, the reader already knows that variables must always start with `$` and function calls are always followed by `(...)`, etc. So you can use the variable and function names as "proper names" (like the names of people, cities, etc) which are *never* preceded by "the". For example

> I changed [the] command `doc('t.xq')` in front of `$p`
>   and `$q` with `$db` as follows. Now it works (plus, I used
>   `last()` to have the last (lowest) common ancestor).

Comment: The Hague......... :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they all are correct. We use the definite article while talking about the 'definite' things. That's why it's definite.

In your sentence, you are talking about the definite command, variables, functions etc. So, yes, putting 'the' is not incorrect.

We say - `open a document in your computer` to refer to 'any document'. But we say, 'open **the** document we had modified last' would specifically point to the specific document modified. This goes with all instances in your example.

Comment: Thank you, I also add another question to my post, please consider that too.

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with [Maulik V's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59374/using-the-before-a-specfic-name/59376#59376).

However, I would like to add one thing.

You use *the* to define one particular variable (class/field/etc..).

There is no better way to answer "which variable?" than to give its exact name, so to me *the variable 'p'* is even too much.

Examples:

> Study Unit 5 for next week
>
> [Turn to Page 394](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/turn-to-page-394)